# dtruss with DYLD_BIND_AT_LAUNCH and sshfs mounts in OSX 10.9?

Tags: c, macos, sshfs, dtruss

I'm trying to build the example at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ecfd80885b9ddf6734192c056cf48bf4) on OSX 10.9:

```bash
cd /tmp
git clone https://gist.github.com/ecfd80885b9ddf6734192c056cf48bf4.git fopentest
cd fopentest
bash buildrun.sh
```

The build succeeds - and furthermore, I can see the following in the terminal output:

```
...
+ DYLD_BIND_AT_LAUNCH=YES
+ ./fopentest.exe ./mytestfile.txt
This is a wrapper function for fopen.
=== this is mytestfile.txt ===
Second line here...
Third line here...
```

That would mean that the call `DYLD_BIND_AT_LAUNCH=YES ./fopentest.exe ./mytestfile.txt` successfully found the wrapper library and function.

Now, just as a test, I'd like to run this executable through `dtruss`, [OSX “strace” equivalent](https://opensourcehacker.com/2011/12/02/osx-strace-equivalent-dtruss-seeing-inside-applications-what-they-do-and-why-they-hang/) - I've also done `sudo chmod u+s /usr/sbin/dtrace` as recommmended in that link. So I try in the `/tmp` folder:

```
$ DYLD_BIND_AT_LAUNCH=YES dtruss ./fopentest.exe ./mytestfile.txt 2>&1 | grep wrap
This is a wrapper function for fopen.
stat64("libwrapper.dylib\0", 0x7FFF5A7DF248, 0x7FFF5A7E00E0)         = 0 0
open("libwrapper.dylib\0", 0x0, 0x0)         = 3 0
write_nocancel(0x1, "This is a wrapper function for fopen.\n=== this is mytestfile.txt ===\nSecond line here...\nThird line here...\n\0", 0x6C)      = 108 0
```

So, clearly `dtruss` here works. However, I have the exact same files in a different directory, and why I try to run the same commands, `dtruss` fails:

```
$ DYLD_BIND_AT_LAUNCH=YES dtruss ./fopentest.exe ./mytestfile.txt 2>&1 | grep wrap
dyld: Library not loaded: libwrapper.dylib
stat64("libwrapper.dylib\0", 0x7FFF4FD85228, 0x7FFF4FD860C0)         = 0 0
open("libwrapper.dylib\0", 0x0, 0x0)         = -1 Err#2
stat64("/Users/MYNAME/lib/libwrapper.dylib\0", 0x7FFF4FD85A08, 0x7FFF4FD860C0)       = -1 Err#2
stat64("/usr/local/lib/libwrapper.dylib\0", 0x7FFF4FD85A08, 0x7FFF4FD860C0)      = -1 Err#2
stat64("/usr/lib/libwrapper.dylib\0", 0x7FFF4FD85A18, 0x7FFF4FD860C0)        = -1 Err#2
```

What could possibly be the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

Hm, I think I understand what the reason is: the directory where `dtruss` fails to find the library, is actually mounted via `sshfs`; `mount` shows this for that path:

```
MYOTHERNAME@myRemotePC:/media/Test1 on /media/Test1 (osxfusefs, nodev, nosuid, synchronous, mounted by MYNAME)
```

So, if I try to call `DYLD_BIND_AT_LAUNCH=YES dtruss ./fopentest.exe ./mytestfile.txt` in `/media/Test1/fopentest/`, then I get the "`dyld: Library not loaded: libwrapper.dylib`".

However, if I move that folder elsewhere in the "proper" filesystem, say in `$HOME`: `mv /media/Test1/fopentest ~/`, I don't even have to rebuild, I can just call the `DYLD_BIND_AT_LAUNCH=YES dtruss ./fopentest.exe ./mytestfile.txt` in `~/fopentest/` and the call succeeds...

Not sure why this happens - so a more informative answer will definitely be appreciated...